# Quite new to Node JS and I am trying to post to a specific request but it get me error

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, web

This is my function to fetch data:

```
let a = showbtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    list.innerHTML='';
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/products')
      .then ( response =>response.json())
      .then( data => {
         data.forEach( product => {
            let li =document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent=` ${product.id} - ${product.name} - $ ${product.price} `;
            list.appendChild(li);
         });
      })
})
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
let express=require('express');
app=express();
//after completing index.html we set index.html as a home page like this by introducing public client folder:
app.use(express.static('public'));
productsArray=[];
//every products must have an id number:
let id=1;
app.use(express.json());

//showing all products:
app.get('/products',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(productsArray);
    

})
//creating ptoducts(posts):
app.post('/products',(req,res)=>{
    let newProduct=req.body;
    newProduct.id=id;
    id++;
    productsArray.push(newProduct);
    res.send('new product created by newProduct=req.body and added to array by push method: Array.push(newProduct)')

    
})
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>shop</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>shop</h1>
    <h2>show all products</h2>
    <button class="show-products">show</button>
    <!-- //everyl ist item is a separate product -->
    <ul class="product-list"></ul>

<!-- //.................................................................... -->
    <h2>add product</h2>
    <form  class="add-product-form">

    <p>
        <label for="add-product-name">
            product:
         
        </label>
        <input id="add-product-name" type="text" >
    </p>


    <p>
        <label for="add-product-price">
            price:
         
        </label>
        <input id="add-product-price" type="text"  >
    </p>
 
    <button>add</button>

    </form>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when i open chrome on localhost:3000 and type something in the field of products and price after that i  click show button but i get this result something like this:

```
1 - undefined - $ undefined
```

the first one is it's id and the second is product name but is undefined and price as well. I think something is wrong with value but i can't solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This problem most likely occures in your `app.js` If you add some console.logs before sending the data and in your response you probably see there a `undefined` as well.

Answer (score 0):

When handling POST bodies in express you need to user `body-parser`

http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

```
npm install body-parser

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Code from the docs

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: thanks but it did not work for me . i add to my code as you mention but it did not solve the problem

Comment: You actually declare your variables incorrectly `productsArray=[];`

Answer (score 0):

in the js file remove the semicolon and replace it with comma